# Is it possible to integrate Sonarqube into azure devops pipeline for a nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, azure, sonarqube

I am trying to run code analysis for a nodejs project using azure devops pipeline. I have created the project in the sonarqube server and a service connection in the project settings of azure. My .yml file contains the following...

```
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SQ-Service'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    projectKey: 'project1'
    projectName: 'project1'
    extraProperties:  |
      sonar.projectKey=project1
      sonar.projectName=project1

...

- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4

- task: SonarQubePublish@4
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

No errors are shown, but analysis does not take place. Please help...

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this working eventually? If so please share your findings and solution...

Comment: scannerMode: 'CLI' worked for me. Hope this helps:)